# How do you tell a browser, "if you need to wrap, wrap here first"?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, html-entities

I'm producing a webpage where a header has a main subject and a descriptor, each of these are wrapped in tags.

I've looked up the [`<wbr>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) tag, and it only seems to work if you have long strings *without* spaces. But I have spaces intermittently in text.

What I need is some thing I can insert between two elements or characters that tells a browser that if it is given the following code:

```
<span>How do you tell a browser,</span><span>"if you need to wrap, wrap here first"<span>
```

Render this:

> How do you tell a browser, "if you to wrap, wrap here first"?

But if there isn't enough space, split between the elements first, giving this:

> How do you tell a browser,
>
> "if you need to wrap, wrap here first"

Then if it shrinks further break the line where ever is needed.

**Is there a character, tag or CSS rule that says "insert a line break *right here* before you even think about putting a line break anywhere else?**

Comment: I actually figured out this could be done with `display:inline-block`, but I'll leave it open to see if there is a more generic way it can be done if the text isn't wrapped nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I messed this up, but yes, of course there is a way

With this code:

```
<span>How do you tell a browser,</span><span>"if you need to wrap, wrap here first"<span>
```

Applying `span {display:inline-block}` in the CSS will force them to be kept together.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the spaces you don't want to break on with `&nbsp;` ? I don't think what you want exists out of the box.

Comment: I had considered that, but I want the other text to wrap as well, *eventually*. What I want to know if I can say "this space is the first to convert".